# How do I change the color of the storyboard to see white text?

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6

I'm building an iphone application with a dark background and some white text. When editing my storyboard the white elements are lost into the background. Is there a way **Purely for Editing** to use a dark background in the storyboard file?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you set the view controller background color in Interface Builder?

Comment: This won't appear in the Storyboard UI...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely! I'm glad you asked this, because it forced me to look into it, and configure IB a little better.

In Interface Builder, go to the Editor Menu - Canvas - select Show Layout Rectangles. If that's not enough, you could add a view, without connecting it to an outlet, and set these properties in IB:

- backgroundColor: black
- hidden - true
- Set it behind smaller views (towards the top), so that you don't have a hassle with view selections

Also, don't add any subviews to it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: how to storyboard background grey color objective c